# Using $ variables in jq from PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, jq

I am using this code:

```
jq --raw-output "(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv" output2.json > output3.csv
```

to create CSV from my JSON database:

```json
[
  {
    "key1": "field1",
    "key2": "field2",
    "key3": "field3"
  },
  {
    "key1": "field4",
    "key2": "field5",
    "key3": "field6"
  }
]
```

The output is perfect on https://jqplay.org/, but doesn't seem to work at all when running on my command line.
I use PowerShell inside VSCode.

I keep getting this error.

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '$' or '[' or '{' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at , 
line 1: (map(keys) | add | unique) as  | map(. as  |  | map([.])) as  | , [] | @csv
jq: 1 compile error
```

I guessed that the `$` were the problem as they are not shown in the error text, so I tried escaping them in various ways but made no progress.
I have searched extensively and no-one seems to have this problem, so I must be getting something very simple very wrong.

Comment: Are you passing this entire line in as a string, or as it is? You'll want to pass it in as a string and escape the | characters. You also need to pay attention to powershell syntax: $ means execute a command in the cmd window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `jq` script:

- **must be passed as a *literal* PowerShell string (`'...'`)**,
- because **an *interpolating* PowerShell string (`"..."`) by design interprets `$`-prefixed tokens as *PowerShell* variable references**; e.g., `$cols` (or PowerShell *subexpressions* (`$(...)`), which doesn't apply in this case):

```bsh
jq -r '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | 
       map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | 
         $cols, $rows[] | @csv' output2.json > output3.csv
```

<sup>* I've added line breaks for readability. PowerShell string literals can span multiple lines, so you should be able to paste the multi-line command as-is. Of course, you can format it as a single line.

* `-r` ensures that the results are output "raw", i.e., without JSON value escaping.

* If you save a `jq` script to a *file* to be used with the `-f` option, be sure to save it as UTF-8 *without a BOM*.</sup>

---

Here's a simplified example that demonstrates the difference:

```bsh
# OK: SINGLE-quoted jq script:
PS> '{ "foo": "bar" }' | jq '. as $cols | .foo'
"bar"

# BROKEN: DOUBLE-quoted jq script: PowerShell expands `$cols` up front, 
#         resulting in an empty string, if no such PowerShell variable exists. 
#         jq then effectively sees '. as  | .foo', which explains the syntax error.
PS> '{ "foo": "bar" }' | jq ". as $cols | .foo"
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '$' or '[' or '{' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
. as  | .foo      
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: solved. The problem with this other issue was the encoding. jq needs UTF-8 without BOM. Anything else throws an error.
Marked as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For reference, when I put your (slightly formatted) filter in a file called `filter.jq`

```
  (map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols
| map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows
| $cols, $rows[]
| @csv
```

and your data in a file called `json.data` and run

```
jq -r -f filter.jq json.data
```

I see the following output

```
"key1","key2","key3"
"field1","field2","field3"
"field4","field5","field6"
```

So the problem is likely in the exact command you're running.  Without seeing that it's difficult to say but putting your filter in a separate file would probably prevent any command-line quoting/escaping problems.